# Import ID's of a table into new table from a CSV value data in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How can i import data from csv or tab delimited text into mysql database table which are not direct values to store. i.e data from some columns in csv need to fetch id's from different tables and it need to stored in child table.

I want to store all values in temp table and import data as may database connection loss if poor connectivity instead of loading each row using php code.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Tried using php code to store complete data in array fetching each row, retrieving

Comment: ids and storing into child table

Comment: show your data format